# How to make simple state presistance work in MS Orleans?

Tags: orleans

I have installed Orleans SDK/Orleans VS Tools both. I created all three projects (Grain, Interface & Silo). I am trying to run them as DevTest host. I was following an example in pluralsight video (it is obviously out of date) and with little help I was able to get up to presistence. To make the presistance work, I need a server configuration file. I [copied the file](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Orleans-Configuration-Guide/Typical-Configurations) and dropped it in the Silo project but for some reason, Orleans can not find it. I checked in the code in [Git if anyone want to see it in its current form](https://github.com/ksunair/IoT.Things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We switch the templates and sample to programmatic config in 1.2.0. Here's where silo configuration is done in your code - https://github.com/ksunair/IoT.Things/blob/master/IoT.TestSilo/OrleansHostWrapper.cs#L137. You can use Chirper sample as an example - https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/tree/master/Samples/Chirper.

Answer (score 1):

Been there..

*"I need a server configuration file. I copied the file and dropped it in the Silo project but for some reason, Orleans can not find it."*

If you include an XML file in the Silo project, it will be in the base directory. The Silo executable needs to find it in its runtime location. Make sure to configure the actual copy to bin\debug. After adding the XML you need to change the property "Copy To Output Directory" in Solution Explorer.

Right click the XML, go Properties, then change the it from "Do not Copy" to "Always Copy".